# Google Chrome and Local Files

Tags: google-chrome

I'm currently building a quick in house "menu" that will allow users to quickly access helpful files on our internal network using the following markup:

```
<a href="File://///NetworkLocation/Volume_Store1.accdb">Access</a>
```

Things work great on Firefox and IE, it opens the file direct from the network folder specified. However I run this in Chrome and no matter what I try in terms of settings etc it keeps insisting on downloading the file locally. Is there anyway to turn this feature off? I get it's a security measure but it really doesn't help here.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: See [so] question [Can Google Chrome open local links?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087894) - requires an extension

Comment: I have tried this, the extension is installed but it doesn't seem to be making much of a difference. Ill keep playing with it for now.